# m2e not working for multi module

Tags: eclipse, maven, module, m2e

I installed m2e and checked-out a multi module project using "Checkout projects using SCM". I can see all modules open as separate projects and it is working fine.  When I try to check-out a different branch of the project using same method (I provide a different name in the "Name template" textbox), it checks-out successfully but all other modules are as just folder.

I tried many different ways but it didn't work.

I can see following error in Maven console: "Project <> already exists", even though there is no project with this name in workspace.

When I create a new workspace then I am able to checkout that branch successfully and everything works fine.

Currently I create a different workspace for a different maven project. Previously I worked with multiple maven projects in a single workspace but it's no longer working.  Does anyone else face this same issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should change "Name template" on last page with selection of projects and after that modules will be available to select for import as projects.

[image]

Comment: I change "Name template" and it open anothe dialog with list of maven module but it is not working.

Comment: For example I've imported projects with name template [artifactId]-[version], now I want to import same project from other place with name template [artifactId]-TRUNK, like here [link](http://i.imgur.com/vtVwDb3.png?1)